# Update and Retrive from Redis using StackExchange Redis package

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using a StackExchange Redis package in my C# application. 
I wanted to know if there is a way to update a value against a key and then retrieve it, avoiding any chances of concurrency issues. I would not want another user to update the key at the same time and the first user then retrieving an incorrect value against the key.

Answer (score 0):

this works pretty well.

```
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(Convert.ToInt32(_configuration.GetConnectionString("database_number")));

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in _dictAllData)
{

    db.StringSet(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2880), When.Always, CommandFlags.DemandMaster);
```